# On integral points of $f(x,y)=z g(x,y)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ be polynomials with integer coefficients.

Consider the surface
$$ f(x,y)=z g(x,y) \qquad (1)$$

(1) has parametrization over the rationals given by
$z=\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$.

> Q1 What are sufficient conditions (1) to have infinitely many
> integer solutions?

Let $D$ be positive integer and let $F(x,y)=x^D+y^D+1,G(x,y)=(x y)^{D-1}+1$

> Q2 Does $F(x,y) =z G(x,y)$ has infinitely many integer solutions (numerical evidence suggest it has)?

**Added later**

Partial results:

Wolfram Alpha can't solve it.

There is reduction to the univariate case which
is better than bruteforce search at the cost of integer
factorization.

Fix $y=y_0$ and let $F(x)=f(x,y_0),G(x)=g(x,y_0)$.
The gcd of the polynomials $F,G$ is divisor $d$ of
their resultant $r$ and we have
$G(x) \mid F(x) \iff \gcd(F(x),G(x))=G(x)=d$,
so we are looking for solutions of $G(x)=d$.

As a special case, can we solve $f=x^4+y^3+1,g=x^3 y^3+2$.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding Q2, one has $F(x, x^{2D-1}+x^{D-1}) = (x^D+1)\cdot G(x, x^{2D-1}+x^{D-1})$, yielding infinitely many integral points.